# Fourier Transform Lemma 2.3 from Stein Singular Integrals

Tags: fourier-transform, singular-integrals

I'm working through Stein Singular Integrals, and can't figure out how to prove this lemma (and find Stein's proof either wrong or un-readable).  It is the following:

### Lemma 3.3

Suppose $K:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following three properties: $$(a)\ \ \ |K(x)| \leq B|x|^{-n} $$ $$(b)\ \ \ \int_{|x|>2|y|}{|K(x-y) - K(x)|dx} \leq B\ \ \ \forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n $$ $$(c)\ \ \ \int_{R_1 < |x| < R_2}{K(x)dx} = 0\ \ \ \forall 0 < R_1 < R_2 < \infty $$

For $\varepsilon > 0$ define $K_\varepsilon(x) = K(x)\chi_{B_\varepsilon}(x)$ where $\chi_{B_\varepsilon}$ is the characteristic function of the ball $B_\varepsilon$ of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at the origin.  Then we have

$$
\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n}{|\mathcal{F}(K_\varepsilon)(y)|} \leq CB
$$

where the $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier Transform, and $C$ is a dimensional constant not depending on $K$ or $\varepsilon$.

#### (end of statement of Lemma 3.3)

First of all, I don't even think this is true unless we interpret the supremum as an essential supremum, but I'm not even concerned about that.  We are to first prove it for the case $\varepsilon = 1$ and then use a scaling argument.  This is fine with me, but I do not understand the case $\varepsilon = 1$.  The main maneuver suggested by Stein is the following:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}{e^{2\pi i y \cdot x} K_1(x) dx} = \cfrac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}{e^{2\pi i y \cdot x} [K_1(x) - K_1(x-z)]dx}
$$

where $z = \cfrac{y}{2|y|^2}$.  Then, how I understand it is, we should split this into an integral over $\{ |x| > 2|z| \}$ and one over $\{ |x| \geq 2|z| \}$.  The first can be estimated with the help of assumption (b), but I do not seem to agree with Stein that the second can be estimated, or I mis-understood what he wrote.  If anyone can give a reference or a hint in the right direction, I'll appreciate it. I've been tinkering with this for far too long, so if I can't get help, I'm going to have to leave this theorem alone...

Comment: Did you find a way to make use of (c) ? Maybe using that if $A$ is an orthogonal matrix then $\mathcal{F}[g(A x)](y) = \mathcal{F}[g(x)](A y)$